# Azure data factory how to fetch source count and sink count for data validation

Tags: azure, error-handling, count, azure-data-factory, paas

I have very genric question. Like I am copy data from storage to sql. For validation I need to check 100 records in or 100 rows in storage in csv form all rows are moved to sql or not. I.e I need to find out the Source records count and destination records count.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKgLc.png)

I need to populated those count in monitor section of user property.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/St3Al.png)

Answer (score 0):

One possible way you could try is to have an additional Wait Activity chained to your Copy Activity and then configure the User Properties of Wait Activity with dynamic expression as below to monitor the number of rows read and copied using Copy Activity from UI.

**User Properties of Wait Activity**

1. `RowsReadFromSource_copyCSVToSQLTable = @string(activity('copyCSVToSQLTable').output.rowsRead)`
2. `RowsCopiedToSink_copyCSVToSQLTable = @string(activity('copyCSVToSQLTable').output.rowsCopied)`

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes Kranthi somehow it is helping in unit testing also, thanks for your explanation.